# Custom middleware in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular 8. Can I make a custom middleware for checking network speed and local storage checking before any component load. Can you please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: try using `resolvers` for that.

Comment: Yes resolvers are great if you need per component based checking, checkout interceptors aswell, they are the closest you can get to middlewares, they catch the request before it leaves the app and catches the resposne before it enters the app. You just have to decide what are your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `resolvers` which is called before any component load like this-

> custom.resolver.ts

```
import {
  Resolve,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export class ActiveResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor() {}

  resolve(_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _rstate: RouterStateSnapshot) {
       <-- your custom logic for speed -->
  }

}
```

> In your app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([     
      {
        path: 'yourcomponent',
        component: yourcomponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        resolve: { ar: ActiveResolver }
      }]
```